# How to get HTMLElement properties before destroy in svelte?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit, flip

There is a simple demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/sveltejs-kit-template-default-qns8y9?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FCard.svelte

In the `Card.svelte`, line 29 - 37, before routing(destroy), the Writable `crossPageState` should remember the location of this Card, but it only remember `{left: 0, top: 0, width: 0, height: 0}`.

I have tried using action and remember the location in the returned `destroy` function, but it still remember the `{left: 0, top: 0, width: 0, height: 0}`

Comment: Include all relevant code *in the question*, ideally create a *minimal* example from scratch.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @H.B. Thans for your reply. The link above is the minimal code. It contains just two pages and the animation requires at least two pages.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `onDestroy` runs *after* the component has been destroyed and thus the element is no longer on the screen. You can fix this by storing the position of your div during `onMount` instead.

```
export let key: string;
let wrapDiv: HTMLDivElement;
let currentPos: ElementState;

onMount(() => { 
  currentPos = getRect(wrapDiv);
  
  const v = $crossPageState;
  if (key in v) {
    const prevPos = v[key];
    const invert = {
      left: prevPos.left - currentPos.left,
      top: prevPos.top - currentPos.top
    };
    const keyframes = [
      { transform: `translate(${invert.left}px, ${invert.top}px)` },
      { transform: `translate(0)` }
    ];
    const options = { duration: 300, easing: "cubic-bezier(0,0,0.32,1)" };
      
    wrapDiv.animate(keyframes, options);
          
  }
});

onDestroy(() => {
  $crossPageState[key] = currentPos
});
```

The important changes:

- store the elements position directly during `onMount` (before animating it)
- use the stored value in `onDestroy`

Less import changes:

- using `get` is discouraged, use the store subscription instead

### Different approach:

You are animating an element between it's position on one page versus it's position on a different page. Consider using the [View Transition API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/View_Transitions_API) for this instead (it is made for it), while as of today it is not fully supported in Safari or Firefox and the cards will simply "jump" in those two browsers, consider how important the animation itself is (does it break functionality or is it just cosmetic?) and that this will likely be supported "soon" in both those browsers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just wanted to do this animation out of interest. If I record the position in the `onMount` function, what if the div's location changes in the future(for example, the div animates after mounted)? So I want to record the location at the very last.

Comment: just restore it every time it changes